# Visual Studio 2013 .NET 4.0 option missing from prerequisites in project options publish

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, vsto, office-addins

I want to deploy an ms-office document-level customisation to target .NET 4.0.
In VS 2013 (and VS 2017 RC), Project/Options/Publish/Prerequisites I only have options for .NET 3.5 or 4.5 and above: no option for 4.0.  This means I can't bundle 4.0 or instruct the installer to download it on the client machine.

[image]

On my windows 7 machine, VS has many more options, including the one I need.

[image]

I checked my registry on the dev machine and the .NET 4.0 node is marked as deprecated.
I tried to fix the problem by downloading .NET 4.0 on the dev machine but the installer refuses to do this because a higher version is already installed and that 4.0 is already included in it.

Is the fact that .NET 4.0 is not directly installed the reason why I don't see that option in VS?  If not, how do I enable it?  Otherwise, how can I publish a solution targeting .NET 4.0, with a particular (bug-free) .NET 4.0 build?

Comment: XP must die.  We could help but that doesn't help us :)  Just copy the bootstrapper in the SDK install directory from the Win7 machine.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks Hans. Thanks for explaining the silence :p